# I need some assistance with vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In the beginning, when I ran my python script with code runner, it ran in output and I couldn't input anything, than I changed it to run in a integrated terminal and it worked properly for a while.

I then started created loops and stuff and bla bla but fo some reason now whenever I run it, it doesn't run properly as in show me the place to write the input but just shows C:\ Desktop
Any fixes for this?

Comment: Could you clarify your problem? such as provide a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to `cd` into the directory where your python script is located, then you should be able to run your python script with `python scriptname.py`.

you could also write `cmd` in the adress bar in your script filepath file explorer.

I hope this is clear enough for you to understand!